# Magento 2, send magento emails via Mailchimp

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, i wants to send all emails(like Customer creation, order creation etc...) via Mailchimp.

Please suggest me is there any script, please navigate me.

Thank you

Comment: First Download Mailchimp for Magento 2 > [https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html](https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html) Then use this tutorial in order to configure Mailchimp in magento2 > [https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/](https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/)

Comment: Hello Muhammad, Thank you for reply.  I checked but mailchimp show option for only Abandoned Cart . I need email for order create, invoice etc.. also. Any idea about it.